# Why is showing error? here is compilation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def findSingle( ar, 5):
    res = ar[0]
    for i in range(1,5):
        res = res ^ ar[i]
    return res

ar = [2, 2, 1, 1, 3]
print "Output", findSingle(ar, len(ar))
```

Comment: You need parentheses in the `print` call. (In Python 2 you did not)

Comment: Also, `5` is not a valid parameter name in `def findSingle( ar, 5):` It is unclear what that is for. Probably can remove it and use `for i in range(1, len(ar)):` or just `for i in ar[1:]:`

Answer (score 0):

1- The first error is in line 1 you give to second argument value and you are already giving it in line 8 `len(ar)`  on the function you should just give the parameters like this `def findSingle(ar, length):`.

2- at line 8 you miss bracket in function `print()`

```
def findSingle(ar, length):
    res = ar[0]
    for i in range(1,5):
        res = res ^ ar[i]
    return res

ar = [2, 2, 1, 1, 3]
print("Output", findSingle(ar, len(ar)))
----------------------------------------

Output 3
```